# How to parse command line args in python

Tags: python, parsing

I want to run a python file with few arguments which would need to be parsed and executed from the script file. for example `c:\file.py -t version -m user -p pwd  -i id.`

How would i parse these and assign the values to the variables.

can u suggest me an example to look into pls

Answer (score 3):

Use the excellent [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) library.  It's standard and works well.

Answer (score 1):

Most folks would recommend `getopt`, as it's pretty stable and very mature.

[Python getopt docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for doing this.